# Bind a subclass to property

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have a simple question. Of course it has many answers but I cannot  choose right keywords to google.
How I can bind a subclass to my wpf control?

For example:
It's my class.

```
    public class SiteFieldInfo<T>
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public T Value { get; set; }
        public List<string> PositiveXPathExpressions { get; set; }
        public List<string> NegativeXPathExpressions { get; set; }
    }

    public class SiteInfo
    {
        public SiteFieldInfo<string> Author { get; set; }
        public SiteFieldInfo<DateTime> Date { get; set; }
        public SiteFieldInfo<string> Source { get; set; } 
    }
```

And I want to bind property Value from SiteFieldInfo to Text property of TextBox control.

C# code:

```
stackPanel1.DataContext = SiteInfoInstance;
```

xaml code:

```
<StackPanel Name="stackPanel1">
<TextBlock Text="Author" />
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Author.Value}" />
</StackPanel>
```

It's not working. What is right syntax or any alternatives?

---

Sorry, It's work well. I am just stupid. How to close question?

Comment: When you say "It's not working"  - what are you seeing?  Are there any binding errors in the output window?

Comment: To close this question you should post the solution even if it was a silly issue so that at least it's helpful for others :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you absolutely positive that your `SiteInfoInstance` is populated with data? I don't see any problems with the way your classes are structured or with your XAML.

Answer (score 0):

Is calling the ToString() method like here in XAML works? I thought the binding will automatically get the string representation of the source of the binding.